# Synchronized Data Extensions in Customer Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, dataextensions, marketing-cloud-connect

I'm facing several issues working on Marketing Cloud because of the lacking documentation about Marketing Cloud available on Salesforce portal.
I have connected Service CLoud with Marketing Cloud and now I have to configure some Customer Journey with Salesforce data (updated in real time). 
So, in order to achieve that, I created synchronized data extensions for the Service Cloud object I need to use.
The question is: Could I use these DEs to feed the Customer Journey? Could I use these DEs for AMP script in the emails?
Thanks for your feedback.
Alessia

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use the synchronized DE's in SQL and in AMPscript - you just have to refer to them with ent."DE Name" (e.g. ent.Contact_Salesforce) to pull information from them. SQL is used if you want to create a specific audience and throw them into a journey or send a campaign to them.

   2. Use "Salesforce Data" as the entry event source in your journeys, in case you want to inject people into the journey at the time the data changes inside salesforce. Be aware that you need to be syncing the object in order for this to work. E.g. to trigger a journey when a contact becomes a customer, you must first synchronize the contact object

Hope this clarifies